# How to check value of each node in the list

Tags: c#, .net, pseudocode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check each node in the list which contains another list and can go deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435957/check-each-node-in-the-list-which-contains-another-list-and-can-go-deeper)

I have List of nodes, again each node can be a list of nodes and it can continue to be more deeper. **Now I want to check all the nodes for a certain string (like a html tag) (which do not have any child list)**.

I want the pseudo code for this. This is not a C# List or IEnumerater, But i am using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to traverse all the htmlnodes in the webpage to check for particular html tag.

Don't tag this question as close...Please add a comment if need more information. But I trying to write generic code...I dont have any id's to search with.

```
public string GetText(HtmlNode htmlNodeTemp)
    {
       foreach (HtmlNode hn in htmlNodeTemp.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (hn.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
            {
                GetText(hn);
            }
            if (hn.SelectSingleNode("//p").OuterHtml.Contains("<p>"))
            {
                if (finalText != null)
                {
                    if (finalText.Length < hn.SelectSingleNode("//p").InnerText.Length)
                    {
                        finalText = hn.SelectSingleNode("//p").InnerText;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    finalText = hn.SelectSingleNode("//p").InnerText;
                }
            }
        }
       return finalText;
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have ignored all of the comments on your identical, (almost) closed question. Address those before you ask again please. Edit your original question if you have more to add to it.

Comment: I posted my response to those comments...please be more specific. I dont have more information to provide.

Comment: Edit the question instead of posting in comments.

Comment: Now see the title that is the question...Check the bold part in the explantion

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a recursive solution and check for the existance of the element. So something like this pseudo code:

```
 Function FindTheNode (CurrentNode)

      Is the current node null?
            Yes -> Return null;

      Is the current node == Search String
            Yes -> return node;

      For each node X in the nodes of current node:
           var node = FindTheNode(X);

           is node non null?
              Yes -> return node

      Return null

  End
```

Comment: I think if goes to recursive at one stage and once that recursive is complete and comes out of it and it should start executing the child node in the main list where it has left the main loop...but loop is not remembering the child node that is should continuing looking into...

Comment: What?  This is a recursive function.  It keeps going deeper into the node lists until it finds the one you are looking for and then returns it.

Comment: yes it goes inside, but its not returning to the list node where it has left the main list to continue its execution for the remaining